# Jupyter notebook outputs pointers

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When plotting, Jupiter outputs weird stuff that looks like pointers or something, see the image:
[image: Jupiter output]

I have no idea how to change it, I didn't find any answers on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a variable to the plot object to capture the output:

`_ = iris.boxplot(by = 'species', figsize = (12, 8))`

[image: solution]

The [underscore is used in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) when you need to assign to a variable that isn't actually used.